# How to use structure with different type variables for buffer data

Tags: opengl

This is the structure

```
struct ttf_point
{
    float x;                      /* point x coordinate in EM */
    float y;                      /* point y coordinate in EM */
    uint32_t spl : 1;             /* point of spliting process */
    uint32_t onc : 1;             /* point on curve */
    uint32_t res : 30;            /* reserved for internal use */
};
```

Can i use the first two variables x and y from the structure to create buffer data or i would need to copy the x , y into another buffer and than use it.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, w_VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  mesh->outline->total_points * sizeof(ttf_point), &mesh->outline->cont->pt->x, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float) + 3 * sizeof(uint32_t), (void*)0);
```

Comment: Of course you can, but you are wasting a lot of memory and having to transfer a lot more data to the GPU than you need.

Comment: Exactly what rabbid said: I suggest you go for structure of arrays instead of arrays of structures. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA